# Unable to use NavigationService in ViewModel when binding View to ViewModel with view code-behind

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm working on a project where I'm using the Prism MVVM architecture with Autofac, trying to create a general footer Navigation Bar that can be utilized by other views.

I'm trying to set a specific binding-context from a View's code-behind to a ViewModel - but unable to do so because the instantiation of the viewmodel requires dependency injection of the navigation service.

**I have the following:**

- A .xaml containing a content view with a navigation bar
  (NavigationBarView.xaml)
- A .xaml containing a content page consisting
  of different views, including the navigation bar view (other Views)

I'm inserting the partial view by doing:

```
<ContentPage 
    ...
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views;assembly=Myproject"
    .../>

<Layout
    ...
    <pages:NavigationBarPage />
    ...
</Layout>
```

As well as the constructor in my code-behind is something like this:

```
public CodeBehindConstructor() {
     BindingContext = new NavigationBarViewModel(requires 
     navigationservice);
}
```

It would be solvable if i could create an instance of the INavigationService in the code behind of the NavigationBarView, but i have not been able to find a way to do so.

My ViewModel Constructor looks like this:

```
public NavigationBarViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        ...
        ...
    }
```

_navigationService is set to a INavigationService that's not initialized, which makes the service unusable.

The binding between the NavigationBarView and NavigationBarViewModel works, but i can't figure out how to handle the dependency injection of the INavigationService.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my Xamarin.Forms applications:
* create a static container located in the Application class (always a descendant of the Application class from XF).

```
public class BaseApplication : Application
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    ...
    ...
}

public BaseApplication(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    ... register all dependencies here ... (don't forget your navigation service)

    Container = builder.Build();
}
```

This class is created by your MainActivity (Android), you MainPage (UWP), etc.

`LoadApplication(new BaseApplication(_containerBuilder));`

When you need to create a view model from your view, you just need

`BindingContext = BaseApplication.Container.Resolve<MyViewModel>();`

Comment: This example shows bad practices... assuming you have a legitimate reason for using the container from the code behind in a View, you should have injected the container and not be trying to access it statically. The answer also fails to address the issue of getting a working NavigationService instance into the ViewModel as `Container.Resolve<MyViewModel>()` doesn't do that by itself.

Comment: @DanS. The Container.Resolve<MyViewModel>() resolves the Navigation Service as the navigation service needs to be registered, as well as your viewmodel.  You should try before telling it's not working.  And this is not bad practice as there is no mechanisms in Xamarin Forms to register another container than its own dependency service ... You should read some documentation before telling it's bad practice...

Comment: I'm telling you as a member of the Prism team your answer promotes bad practices and will not provide a working instance of the INavigationService. See the answer I provided for more explanation.

Comment: I might add that INavigationService is a named service. We specifically don't advertise the name with the container which means that even if your ViewModel had the `navigationService` name, depending on the container it will either resolve `INavigationService` as null or through an exception. The ONLY way for it to properly resolve is through the ViewModelLocationProvider. If you had read the docs or had a proper understanding of how Prism works you might now this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question in case anyone else stumbles upon this (as I did).

Prism v7.x now has the option to connect the viewmodel of the partialview in XAML to the parent Page using
**prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView** attribute.

1. Create the partial view and a viewmodel for it as per normal.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.MyPartial">
  <StackLayout>       
    <Label Text="Please wait...." IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchLabelVisible}"/>
  </StackLayout>    
</ContentView>
```

2. Register the view and it's matching viewmodel in the App.xaml.cs thus:
   `ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(typeof(MyPartial).ToString(), typeof(MyPartialViewModel));`
3. Now drop the partial view into the host page.
   Be sure to declare the namespace in the header area

```
    ...
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.HostPage"
    x:Name="HostPageName"
    Title="Input ISBN"
    ....
```

```
<uc:MyPartial prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference HostPageName}"/>
```

This connects the partial with the host page and so the viewmodel of the partial can be declared as of type ContentPage 
and therefore be able to instantiate all the usual page services, such as navigationService and eventAggregator.

```
public class MyPartialViewModel : BaseViewModel
...
public bool IsSearchLabelVisible {get; set;}

public MyPartialViewModel(INavigationService navigationService,
                          IEventAggregator eventAgregatorService,
                          IPageDialogService dialogService)
            : base(navigationService, eventAgregatorService)
...
```

The link to this [AutoWirePartialView with prism does not work or badly used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896129/autowirepartialview-with-prism-does-not-work-or-badly-used)
set me on the right path.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can AutoWire the ViewModel so long as you maintain the convention you would with any other view. Where you run into problems is that Prism doesn't currently support injecting the NavigationService into a ViewModel for a Custom View out of the box. Navigation within Xamarin Forms is dependent on an understanding of what page you are navigating from. To simply resolve `INavigationService` would result in a NavigationService with no concept of the Page it's navigating from and would entirely mess up your navigation.

First of all you'll want to take note of the [ConfigureViewModelLocator](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Autofac.Forms/PrismApplication.cs#L50-L63) method in the PrismApplication. You'll notice that by default Prism only handles a 'view' object that is a Page. You'll want to update this to handle the case where it is a view and then you can walk up the ParentView until you get to a Parent that is a Page.

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((view, type) =>
    {
        NamedParameter parameter = null;

        switch(view)
        {
            case Page page:
                parameter = new NamedParameter("navigationService", CreateNavigationService(page));
                break;
            case View customView:
                var page = GetPage(customView);
                parameter = new NamedParameter("navigationService", CreateNavigationService(page));
                break;
        }

        return Container.Resolve(type, parameter);
    });
}

private Page GetPage(View view)
{
    switch(view.ParentView)
    {
        case Page page:
            return page;
        case null:
            return null;
        default:
            return GetPage(view.ParentView)
    }
}
```

If for some reason you are not following the conventions and do not want to explicitly set the AutoWire property, you can do something like:

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(typeof(NavigationBarView).ToString(),
                                   typeof(NavigationBarViewModel));
```