# AutoWirePartialView with prism does not work or badly used?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, partial-views, autowired

I'm trying to use prism 7.1 `AutoWirePartialView` to bind a `PartialView` to its viewModel. However, binding is not working, or at least, setting the viewModel to the `PartialView` does not seem to work, it still has the page's BindingContext as BindingContext.

**There is my Page** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
             x:Class="Project.Core.Views.NotConnectedViews.ForecastDemoPage"
             xmlns:carouselForecast="clr-namespace:Project.Core.Views.MainViews"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             x:Name="ForecastDemo"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColorOne}" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainAppTemplate}">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="SearchForecast" Command="{Binding ShowSearchForecastDemoCommand}" Order="Primary" Icon="ic_search_white_24dp.png" Priority="0" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentView x:Name="ContentViewForecast"  ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ForecastTownControlTemplate}">
        <carouselForecast:ForecastPartialViewCarousel prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference ForecastDemo}"></carouselForecast:ForecastPartialViewCarousel>
    </ContentView>

</ContentPage>
```

> Binding: 'DayWeatherForecasts' property not found on
>   'Project.Core.ViewModels.ForecastDemoPageViewModel', target property:
>   'Project.Core.Views.MainViews.ForecastPartialViewCarousel.ItemsSource'

As you can see, I'm using the partial view as a `ContentPresenter` for a `ContentView` that uses a `ControlTemplate`.

**There is my PartialView :**

```
<carousel:CarouselViewControl x:Name="carouselView" 
                              Position="{Binding CarouselPosition}" 
                              PositionSelectedCommand="{Binding PositionChanged}" 
                              Orientation="Horizontal" AnimateTransition="True" IsSwipeEnabled="False" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DayWeatherForecasts}" InterPageSpacing="10"
                              xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                              xmlns:carousel="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
                              x:Class="Project.Core.Views.MainViews.ForecastPartialViewCarousel">
    <!-- Item template is defined here, removed for readability -->
</carousel:CarouselViewControl>
```

**And this is my PartialView ViewModel** :

```
namespace Project.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class ForecastPartialViewCarouselViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public ForecastPartialViewCarouselViewModel(IForecastService forecastService,
            INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            InitStubForecasts();
        }


        private ObservableCollection<DayWeatherForecast> _dayWeatherForecasts;

        public ObservableCollection<DayWeatherForecast> DayWeatherForecasts
        {
            get => _dayWeatherForecasts;
            set => SetProperty(ref _dayWeatherForecasts, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course `DayWeatherForecasts` is set with some stub values. I simplified the viewModel for readability purpose.

I'm not using prism AutoWiring viewModel, so in app.xaml.cs :

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ForecastDemoPage, ForecastDemoPageViewModel>();
```

Question : Could it be that my `PartialViewModel` is in the ViewModels folder and that the Partialview I want to be be bound to this ViewModel is under a subfolder `MainViews` ? Should I create a `MainViewsViewModel` folder and put my viewModel there ?

EDIT : I tried this solution, but as I expected it does nothing.

If not, then I don't know why it doesnt work ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I finally found out that its **not enough** to put this to my `PartialView`

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference ForecastDemo}
```

As I organized my views in subfolders, prism cannot register alone my `ViewModel` and my `PartialView`.

So what I needed is to register manually the `ViewModel` with the `PartialView` using `ViewModelLocationProvider`

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) 
{ 
   ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ForecastPartialViewCarousel,
   ForecastPartialViewCarouselViewModel>(); 
}
```

It's not only a matter of name, but of namespace too. If I wanted the `PartialView` to have the correct `ViewModel` set w/o registering it manually, I should have put my `PartialView` in the *Views* root folder and the corresponding `ViewModel` in the *ViewModels* root folder (with naming convention)

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but the BindingContext property in the code behind is null. Do you know why? How could I get the partial view view model?

Comment: @jcasas Where and when do you try to get your view's view model in codebehind ? I think your best option is to get it in the `OnBindingContextChanged` method of your view. As you noticed it might be null in your view's constructor as we don't really know when prism will set it.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! In the event the view model is already set.

Comment: Glad it helped !

Comment: Hi @Umar3x - your point about ViewModelLocationProvider helped me set the binding context. However, my commands are not working. Were you able to get commands to work?

Comment: Yes all my commands work. If you got the binding context, then it should work. Maybe you got a probleme with the Binding Syntax ? Where is your view  ?

Comment: @Umar3x - my custom ContentView is in a separate folder to the Views folder that I keep my pages in. I see the ViewModel constructor is called, and even the Command when the first program is run. But trying to execute the command from a button afterwards does not work.

Comment: It's working! Not sure if I had to do a clean and rebuild of my Xaml but I first got it working for labels, then a button and now my custom control.

Comment: Ok, nice news :). As long as you use ViewModelLocationProvider it should work. If you still have some prob, check your exception settings.

Comment: I now have another problem. To take your example in your answer, what if I wanted to re-use ForecastPartialViewCarousel and register it with a different ViewModel else-where in the application?

Comment: Why would you do that ? How different is your VM compared to previous ? Maybe you should consider split your partial view in different components that can have their own bindingContext too . Or, have two partial views.

Comment: Hello Umar, I'm having the same problem. I'm kind of stuck. Can you please tke a look at this question I asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426282/setting-my-partial-view-not-working-xamarin . I would really really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Pavel I refactored my whole code to take advantages of the Regions introduced in Prism.Forms.