# Setting my partial View, not working xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Now I got started with Prism Framework for xamarine, but I'm having a little problem achieving connections across  views.

I have this folder "Views" and inside it I have another folder called PartialViews. Now inside PartialViews I have a contentPage called "Header.xaml".
Now I would like to atach this file to the Index.xaml view, which is located in the Views folder. I would like to atach the "Header.xaml" to other views also, like for example I would like to atach it to the "Orders.xaml" view.

My Header.xaml file is as follows :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PROJECTX.Views"
                     prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                     x:Class="PROJECTX.Views.Header">

            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Trying partial views" />
            </StackLayout>

        </ContentPage>
```

While my Index.xaml is as follows:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:combobox="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.ComboBox;assembly=Syncfusion.SfComboBox.XForms"
        xmlns:ListCollection="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PROJECTX.Views"
                     prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                     x:Class="PROJECTX.Views.Index"
                     x:Name="selfi">


            <ScrollView>
                <local:Header mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference selfi}" />

                <combobox:SfComboBox x:Name="comboBox">
                    <combobox:SfComboBox.ComboBoxSource>
                        <ListCollection:List x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <x:String>Rendit sipas: Me te kerkuara</x:String>
                            <x:String>Rendit sipas: Te fundit</x:String>
                            <x:String>Rendit sipas: Alfabetit</x:String>
                        </ListCollection:List>
                    </combobox:SfComboBox.ComboBoxSource>
                </combobox:SfComboBox>


            </ScrollView>

        </ContentPage>
```

I also registred on my App.xaml.cs the routing of the PartialViews folder with the view model like this:

```
        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
          {
              containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
              containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
              containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Index, IndexViewModel>();
              //containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Header, HeaderViewModel>();
              ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<Header, HeaderViewModel>();
          }
```

Now I get a few errors...

```
1. The property 'Content' is set more than once. 
2. The attachable property 'AutowirePartialView' was not found in type 'ViewModelLocator'.
3. Property 'Content' does not support values of type 'Header'.
```

Now I know this might be a rookie question, but I just can't seem to get it to work this partial views thing.
Is my understanding of partial views in xamarin correct? I'm supposed to call the partial view from the view.. correct?

Any help I would really really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to understand that in Xamarin forms, you can only have one ContentPage object for a page, hence you are getting the error “Content is set more than once”. You can however have multiple Layouts inside a single page
[Here](https://youtu.be/-2TZpsUJEjk?t=480)’s a quick snippet explaining pages versus layouts

Since you’re looking to use the Prism "PartialViews", a common way of referencing them is a "Template". So you’d have a HeaderTemplate file as you have shared. But instead of a ContentPage object, you would use a ContentView object (which is of type Layout) and you would define the content of the header inside that. ([Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview))

And then you can add it to any page using this line inside your XAML as you would add a regular layout:

`<templates: HeaderTemplate/>`

Comment: No @saamer.. I think I got the concept quite clear...  I think you got it wrong mate. Let me rephrase you from the Prism documentation : " ~The concept of a Partial View is to support a custom layout which may be reused across multiple pages, and eliminate ViewModel logic duplication by allowing that custom layout to rely on its own ViewModel. ~ " This is what I'm trying to accomplish. I already know what xamarin is, I developed 2 applications 2years ago. Now I got back to it again, and noticed there were some changes.... Maybe you should take a look at Prism framework  :)

Comment: Ah I see. Just noticed the Prism tag. Let me update my answer

Comment: Still @saamer I get the same errors. I updated me Header view, I removed the contentPage and added ContentView instead. But no luck. Maybe you can take a look here, https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.1.0 and see If you get it right, since I think you have more eksperience than me.

Comment: @Pavel dont forget to add XAML compilation to get better error reporting. `[assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc Also, you can't just change the XAML code to ContentView and keep the Xaml.cs page to inherit a ContentPage type. Add a new class of type ContentView so you can reduce confusion.

Comment: Also @Pavel, it seems like you are still missing the point about ContentPage (Pages) and ContentViews (Layouts). You cannot place Index contentPage inside a MainPage or any other page. You would keep the index page as a page to which you would navigate, and it would contain your Header template. I would strongly suggest just reverting to a working state of the app, and then adding templates to the existing page, so you can understand it

Comment: Yes @Saamer , I already started me project. For now I have everything in one page, but I'm hoping to get an answer here. My intention here is to put the header PartialView, inside the  index primary view. Yess, that's the idea, keep the index page as a page to which I would navigate, and it would contain my Header template. We're thinking the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212573/discussion-between-saamer-and-pavel).